# Extracting parameter values from evaluation of parametric solution

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations

I have this system of differential equations :

$\frac{dX}{dt} = (0.8+0.4c_{1})X-(0.007+0.006c_{2})XY$

$\frac{dY}{dt} = (0.048+0.004c_{3})XY-(0.4+0.2c_{4})Y$

where $c_{i}$s are parameters.

I solve the system using the follwing code :

```
   sol = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == (0.8 + 0.4 c1) x[t] - (0.009 + 0.002 c2) x[t] y[t], 
   y'[t] == (0.0049 + 0.0002 c3) x[t] y[t] - (0.4 + 0.2 c4) y[t], 
   x[0] == 200, y[0] == 80}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 25}, {c1, c2, c3, c4}]
```

I then set the parameter values as $c_{i}=\{0,1\}$ for $ i=1,2,3,4$. I tabulate the results using the following code :

```
xt = Flatten[Evaluate[Table[x[c1, c2, c3, c4][t] /.sol, 
            {c1, {0, 1}}, {c2, {0, 1}}, {c3, {0, 1}}, {c4, {0, 1}}]]] //MatrixForm
```

This gives the following output

[image]

**Question 1**
How do I know which `InterpolatingFunction` corresponds to which particular combination of $c_{i}$ ?

Now I evaluate all the `InterpolatingFunction` for $t=0(0.25)25$ using this code :

```
mat = Table[Table[Evaluate[xt[[a]]], {t, 0, 25, 2.5}], {a,Range[Length[xt]]}] // MatrixForm
```

giving the following output :

[image]

**Question 2**

Each row in the above matrix displays the evaluation of one of the `InterpolatingFunction` for $t=0(0.25)25$. I need to get the columnwise maximum(and minimum) for this matrix at $t=0,5,10,...,25$ and want to identify which `InterpolatingFunction` it comes from.

I got the maximum using

```
l = Min /@ Transpose[mat]
```

But couldn't identify which `InterpolatingFunction` the maximums come from.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something like `Flatten[Table[{{c1, c2, c3, c4}, x[c1, c2, c3, c4][t] /.sol}, {c1, {0, 1}}, {c2, {0, 1}}, {c3, {0, 1}}, {c4, {0, 1}}], 3]`, then?

Comment: That does it. What does the `3` at the end do? And what about the second question?

Comment: "What does the `3` at the end do?" - at this point, what you should be doing instead is to look at the docs for `Flatten[]`. ;)

Comment: Yeah. I should do it myself. Thanks for the heads-up though.

Answer (score 1):

One way to make the table from `NDSolve` is,

```
points = Permutations[{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {4}];
datax = TableForm[Table[Flatten[{t,Table[{x[c1, c2, c3, c4][t] /. sol}, {c1, {0, 1}}, 
{c2, {0,1}}, {c3, {0, 1}}, {c4, {0, 1}}]}], {t, 0, 10, 0.5}], 
      TableHeadings -> {None, Prepend[Array["x", Length[points]], t]}]
```

[image]

```
datay = TableForm[Table[Flatten[{t,Table[{y[c1, c2, c3, c4][t] /. sol}, {c1, {0, 1}}, 
    {c2, {0,1}}, {c3, {0, 1}}, {c4, {0, 1}}]}], {t, 0, 10, 0.5}], 
          TableHeadings -> {None, Prepend[Array["y", Length[points]], t]}]
```

[image]

I don't know, how to make the headings for the column automated.